# how change size of section and paragraph

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to change the size of the title of the section, subsection, subsubsection and paragraph my code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}
```

but I want

```
section=arial 12pts
subsection=arial 11.5pts
subsubsecction=arial 11pts
and paragraph=arial 11pts
```

Comment: the `titlesec` package could help you : `\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape\bfseries\Large}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\Large}`

Comment: Please tell us which LaTeX format you use (pdfLaTeX? XeLaTeX? LuaLaTeX? something else?). Should the sectioning headers be typeset in **bold** or in normal weight?

Comment: @Mico 
How do I find out what format I'm using? just install miktex

Comment: @x-rw - Do you know how to open the log file? The first line in the log file should tell you when ch format is in use.

Comment: @Mico the first is pdflatex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sectsty` package to achieve your objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{helvet} % (Arial is an Helvetica clone...)

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{11.5pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
\paragraphfont{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % just for this example

\section{Hello World}
\subsection{In the Beginning}
\subsubsection{First Steps}
\paragraph{Let's Go!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i try to compile and show error: sectsty not found

Comment: @x-rw - Do you know how to run the MikTeX Package Manager utility to install packages? Alternatively, did you consider the full version of MikTeX that includes all packages from the get-go?

Comment: only needed to update, now if it works